# Enable onMouseOut for disabled elements in the html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, onmouseout, react-rails

In react-rails, the onMouseOut event works only if the element is not disabled.

Following is the code in the render method:

```
dom.button
        type: 'submit'
        'data-toggle': "popover"
        title: "Form Requirements"
        'data-content': 'Please fill in all the form fields before submitting this form'
        'data-placement': "bottom"
        className: 'btn btn-primary'
        disabled: !@valid()
        onMouseEnter: @showPopOver
        onMouseOut: @hidePopOver
        'Create admin'
```

The corresponding methods called are shown below:

```
showPopOver: function() {
  if (!this.valid()) {
    return $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');
  }
},
hidePopOver: function() {
  return $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('destroy');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how HTML works. No events for disabled elements. You'll have to make it "appear" to be disabled by other means if you want the events to trigger.

Comment: but onMouseEnter event works, then why onMouseOut doesn't. and this event works on firefox